# Reading, calculate and group data of several files with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a small script to automate something at my work. I have a ton of text files that I need to group into a large dataframe to plot after.

The files have this general structure like this

```
5.013130280 4258.0
5.039390845 4198.0
...         ...
49.944957015 858.0
49.971217580 833.0
```

What I want to do is

1. Keep the first column as the column of the final dataframe (as these values are the same for all files)
2. The rest of the dataframe is just extracting the second column of each file, normalize it and group everything together.
3. Use the file name as the header for extracted column (from point to) to use after in the plotting of the data

Right I was able to only make step 2, here is the code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = "mypath"
extension = 'xy'
os.chdir(path)
dir = os.listdir(path)

files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xy")

li = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, names=('angle','int'), delim_whitespace=True)
    df['int_n']=data['int']/data['int'].max()
    li_norm.append(df['int_n'])
    
norm_files = pd.concat(li_norm, axis = 1)
```

So is there any way to solve this in an easy way?

Comment: any particular reason why you're adding the data as extra columns and not as rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all of your files have exactly the same length (# of rows) and values for angles, then you don't really need to make a bunch of dataframes and concatenate them all together.

If I'm understanding correctly, you just want a final dataframe with a new column for each file (named with the filename) with the 'int' data, normalized with all the values from only that specific file

On the first file, you can create a dataframe to use as your final output, then just add columns to it on each subsequent file

```
for idx,file in enumerate(files):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, names=('angle','int'), delim_whitespace=True)
    filename = file.split('\\')[-1][:-3] #get filename from splitting full path and removing last 3 characters (file extension)
    df[filename]=df['int']/df['int'].max()    #use the filename itself as the new column name

    if idx == 0:    #create norm_files output dataframe on first file
        norm_files = df[['angle',file]]
    else:           #add column to norm_files for all subsequent files
        norm_files[file] = df[file]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, the only problem is that it is adding the full path and file name to the header row and I want only the file name (excluding path and extension)

Comment: A bit hacky, but I edited my answer to get just the file name by splitting on '\\' and removing the last 3 characters to remove the extension

Answer (score 0):

You can add a calculated column quite simply, although I'm not sure if that's what you're asking.

```py
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, names=('angle','int'), delim_whitespace=True)
    df[file.split('.')[0]]=data['int']/data['int'].max()
    li_norm.append(df['int_n'])
```

Comment: I was able to normalize the data, what is missing is adding the name of the file into the column with the respective data and how to extract the first column from one of the files and add it as the first column of them to the final dataframe